# Conversion of YYYY-MM format to ShortMonth-YYYY format in Data prep

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

I've my incoming data from Client in the format of 2019-09 format whereas we wanted to convert this into Sep 2019 format using Data Prep GUI.

I didn't find solution with Data Prep GUI, please help me with it.

I've tried Data Format options, but no luck

Example Data    Expected Data
2018-06 Jun 2018
2019-08 Aug 2019

No errors

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will have to do. See image for wrangle recipe.

[image]